# How to filter unique values in a column using excel formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm in need of a solution for my excel workbook. I have a column with duplicate values in sheet1 and want to display the unique values of that column in sheet2. 
May be it looks simple but whenever there is a change in values in sheet1 those values should reflect in sheet2. 
I need an excel formula but not the VBA.

I tried few different options like array and stuff but could not able to get the proper solution. Appreciate your timely help. Many Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this tutorial http://www.globaliconnect.com/excel/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=97:remove-duplicates-or-create-a-list-of-unique-records-using-excel-formula&catid=77&Itemid=473

Comment: did you considered using pivot table?

Comment: Thank you @Charles.. i shall check and get back in case i need any support.

Comment: @Dubison - Thought of considering pivot table but i'm collecting data from different sheets based on the unique values to generate a dynamic report. In parallel i shall try this pivot option too. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Say the *Sheet1* table is from **A1** thru **A100**

In *Sheet2* cell **A1** enter:

```
=Sheet1!A1
```

In *Sheet2* cell **A2** enter the array formula:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100,INT(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)=0,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)+(COLUMN(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)*0.01)),1)),100*MOD(SMALL(IF(COUNTIF(A$1:A1,Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)=0,ROW(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)+(COLUMN(Sheet1!$A$1:$A$100)*0.01)),1),1)),"")
```

and copy down.

**Array formulas** must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> rather than just the <kbd>Enter</kbd> key.

Adjust the $A$1:$A$100 to match the exact size in *Sheet1*.

If you can apply a *"helper"* column in *Sheet1,* the formula can be tremendously simplified.

Comment: Thank you so much. And what i have noticed is, if the entire column is selected instead of a defined range (A1 thru A100 in sheet1).. Values are not dispalying in sheet 2. I think a liitle modification would help me to sort out this issue. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @RaviKumarMeduri If you pick the **entire** column, it will take a very, very long time to calculate the array formulas.  **Consider the helper column.**

Comment: Unfortunately the data is exported from the data base on to the sheet and can't formulate it with helper column... . Thank you so much for the extended support. it would really helpful if i get the permanent fix with the formula... .