# Excel formula: Reduce vector to unique values

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Excel 2013. I have a column-vector of several values, some are unique, others not, for example `A1:A7`:

```
981
981
19018
8313
8842
8842
8314
```

I'm looking for a formula that I can paste down another column that results in:

```
981
19018
8313
8842
8314
```

I've found a similar question [How to filter unique values in a column using excel formula](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28676411/how-to-filter-unique-values-in-a-column-using-excel-formula), but the solution didn't work for me (and I didn't really understand the formula)

Comment: Try `pivot` that should work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all `Data>Remove Duplicates` works as a charm.

However, if you want something that will be in formula form (given that your values are in range `A1:A7`) use this formula in `B2`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$1:$A$7,MATCH(0,COUNTIF(B$1:B1,$A$1:$A$7),0)),"")
```

This is an array formula that is applied with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> instead of usual <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

Now you can drag this formula until you get empty values.

This will, basically, return the value from range `A1:A7` if it hasn't returned it already, and once it has exhausted all the values it returns blank cells.

Comment: Sufficient and easier to understand than the [formula in the marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28678524/3104974)